# Static type of the exception object

Tags: c++, try-catch, throw, static-typing, dynamic-binding

I read the following from C++ Primer (5th edition, Section 18.1.1):
"When we throw an expression, the static, compile-time type of that expression determines the type of the exception object." So I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& os){os << "Base\n";}
};

class Derived: public Base{
  public:
  void print(std::ostream& os){os << "Derived\n";}
};

int main(){
  try{
    Derived d;
    Base &b = d;
    b.print(std::cout); //line 1
    throw b;
  }
  catch(Base& c){
    c.print(std::cout); //line 2
  }
return 0;
}
```

which gives me the following output:

```
Derived
Base
```

I think I understand why this output is expected: at line 1, we have dynamic binding. Now when we throw b, it is based on the static type of b, which means both the static type and the dynamic type of c is Base&, and therefore we see the result at line 2.

However, if I were to use a pointer, instead of a reference:

```
 int main(){
  try{
    Derived d;
    Base *b = &d;
    b->print(std::cout); //line 1
    throw b;
  }
  catch(Base* c){
    c->print(std::cout); //line 2
  }
return 0;
}
```

the output now becomes:

```
Derived
Derived
```

which seems to imply that the static type of c is Base*, but the dynamic type of c is Derived*, why? Shouldn't both the static and the dynamic types of c be Base*?

Comment: In the first case, the object is sliced.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks! What are the static type and dynamic type of the expression b in the second case? Base* and Derived*, respectively?

Comment: Expressions don't have a dynamic type, only objects do.

Comment: The book is trying to simplify some very complex principles of the language to newcomers. An expression can evaluate to something that names an object. The static type of the object is the type of the expression (sometimes adjusted). But only the object has a dynamic type, formally.

Comment: @StoryTeller To conclude, each expression has a static type but does not have a dynamic type, am I on the right track? If so, what is the static type of expression b? Is it Base*?

Comment: In the second case? Yes, it's `Base*` (a pointer type).

Comment: I rolled back your "add another question". Please don't do that. It invalidates existing answers and risks turning this post into a way too broad one. If you have a follow up question, then post it as another question. You can link back to this one from the new one, to avoid repeating too many details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When we throw an expression, the static, compile-time type of that expression determines the type of the exception object

The above is entirely true. What you forget, is that pointers are objects too. And when you throw a pointer, **that's your exception object**.

The object you **should have** dynamically<sup>1</sup> allocated is still pointed to by that `Base*` pointer. And no slicing occurs on it, because there is no attempt to copy it. As such, dynamic dispatch via-pointer accesses a `Derived` object, and that object will use the overriding function.

This "discrepancy" is why it is usually best to construct the exception object in the throw expression itself.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> That pointer points to a local object, you did a big no no there and got yourself a dangling pointer.</sub>

Comment: Thanks!! I see the dangling pointer now. What about the first case? Did I have a "dangling reference" or not?

Comment: @ivy - No. In the first case the exception object is a `Base` (The type `T&` is adjusted to `T` in most expressions). So the referred to object was *copied*, and hence I told you it was sliced.

Comment: Can all these be considered as consequences of the fact that when we use the throw operation, the first step would be to copy initialize a temporary exception object from the expression? That is, it is as if I did `Base e = b;  e.print(std::cout);` in the first case (here b is a reference) and `Base* e = b;  e->print(std::cout);` in the second case (here b is a pointer). Is this the right way of thinking? (Still cannot get my ahead around the static vs dynamic typing...).

Comment: @ivy - You can think of this as what's happening. There's only one minor point, and that is how you catch. If you do so by value, and not by reference, the exception object is copied again into the catch clause.

Answer (score 2):

In first case you are throwing a fresh instance of `Base` class invoking a copy constructor because you are passing a reference to `Base` into `throw` operator.

In second case you are throwing a pointer to a stack-allocated object of type `Derived` that goes out of scope when exception is thrown so then you capture and then dereference a dangling pointer causing Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**First scenario**

I think that if you add some prints to your classes, you could see a clearer picture:

```
struct Base {
    Base() { std::cout << "Base c'tor\n"; }
    Base(const Base &) { std::cout << "Base copy c'tor\n"; }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) { std::cout << "Base print\n"; }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived() { std::cout << "Derived c'tor\n"; }
    Derived(const Derived &) { std::cout << "Derived copy c'tor\n"; }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) { std::cout << "Derived print\n"; }
};
```

And the output is:

```
Base c'tor
Derived c'tor
Derived print
throwing // Printed right before `throw b;` in main()
Base copy c'tor
Base print
```

As you can see, when calling `throw b;` there is a copy construction of a different temporary `Base` object for the exception. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> First, copy-initializes the exception object from expression

This copy-initialization **slices** the object, as if you assigned `Base c = b`

**Second scenario**

First, you are throwing a pointer to a local object, causing **undefined behavior**, please avoid that by all means!

Let's say you fix that, and you throw a dynamically allocated pointer, it works since you are throwing a pointer, which doesn't affect the object and preserves dynamic type information.